# Error CS0103 at hosting provider (staging server) but not in my machine

Tags: c#, global-variables

I get an error to the server I upload my files (it is working fine in my machine):

> Compiler Error Message: CS0103:The name 'recipe_time' does not exist in the current context Line 100:

```
<input id="recipe_time" name="recipe_time" type="hidden" 
value="<% =recipe_time %>" />
```

ok, the obvious explanation is that I should declare `recipe_time` but it is already declared in my code in my `Site.Master` file (used by Default.aspx):

```
...
public partial class SiteMaster : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    public int recipe_time = 0;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    ...
    }
    ....
}
....
```

Any ideas why is that happening at the staging server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted everything on the staging server and reuploaded! That fixed the problem!

Maybe something wasn't replaced when i uploaded over FTP without clearing the previous aspx generated files